# Ubuntu 18.04 - Error in network definition

Tags: networking

I'm trying to set static IP for my server and I'm getting this error https://prnt.sc/kalhj5
My other server (v16.04) is working https://prnt.sc/kalkub just fine with same setting (IP is different). 
Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `via: ` should be `- via: ` maybe

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an space to indent routes section:

```
routes:
   - to: 0.0.0.0/0
     via: 10.11.0.6
```

not

```
routes:
- to: 0.0.0.0/0
via: 10.11.0.6
```

Comment: Thanks! just in case someone runs into same issue here's what worked:
https://pastebin.com/3bv6e4Vj